# Is it possible to flag a user rather than just individual posts?

Tags: support, spam

Came across an answer by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423526/gucci-bags) on on one of my favourites, the answer was clearly spam so I flagged it, but then so are all their other answers.  Is it possible to flag the user as spam rather than going through all the answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just flag one of the spam answers for moderator attention, hinting the repeated spamming activity. The mods are trained to handle such situations :)

Comment: Agreed, this is the regular procedure for now. We go through their posting history anyway, one flag is enough. What we do with them after is undisclosed and unsuitable for children anyway.

Comment: OK, flagged and brought to the attention of the moderators.

Comment: I don't believe the moderators actually receive any formal training. More like combat training. "Here's a rifle, go kill some folk."

Comment: There's def. no training involved. BTW, Shadow's answer is now the preferred method.

Answer (score 11):

<s>This is now possible, you can report a user directly from within the profile page:</s>

...and it's gone. Leaving this answer here in case it would show up again, or until getting official response that it won't be back.

Comment: The feature was intended for flagging a *profile* that was broadly offensive, but was mostly being used for situations where users should have been flagging a post, or where someone had an issue with a user (spam, suspected downvoting, Etc.) We may bring it back if we think we can target its use better, but it wasn't working as intended.

Comment: Thanks @Jaydles can you please answer [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243284/report-this-profile-link-is-missing) before I delete this now outdated answer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go through all the answers. Leave a comment when you're flagging a particular user, to note that it is a spam user, rather than spam post, and that should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Flagging users has been discussed and rejected a number of times:

[Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users/1355#1355)

[How do you flag a user to the moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21869/how-do-you-flag-a-user-to-the-moderators/21872#21872)

[Area51: How do I flag a user? (And, Area51 policies therein?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57706/area51-how-do-i-flag-a-user-and-area51-policies-therein)