# How do I flag a user with no posts left?

Tags: support, spam

I just came across a spam and flagged it as is. It was quickly removed but then I noticed a problem:
[This user (removed)](https://stackexchange.com/users/2519139/user2293336?tab=accounts) is on a spamming spree across the Stack Exchange network.

The spam post

> What is the best way to tour China if you don't speak the language?

is on:

- [english.SE (deleted)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112696/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language) | [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:english.stackexchange.com/questions/112696/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language)
- [cooking.SE (deleted)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33805/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language) | [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33805/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language)
- [math.SE (deleted)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375049/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language) | [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:math.stackexchange.com/questions/375049/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language)
- [MSO (deleted)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178219/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language)
- and 3 other sites

And there is no sign of him ever stopping - he just created the 8th account on the network.

This user should be removed and banned. Yet [I can't flag him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61468/is-it-possible-to-flag-a-user-rather-than-just-individual-posts) because his only spam on this site has been removed.

Comment: Well, on [Super User](http://superuser.com/users/219128/user2293336) he got suspended for three years "for promotional content". :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How do I flag a user with no posts left?

You just did. ;)

Comment: Or alternatively fill in the form at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other

Comment: @Rory But... that... won't... give... you... any... precious... Meta... rep... O_o

Comment: @Yannis "Precious Meta rep". That made me chuckle

Answer (score 4):

Just flag a different post, choose Other and clearly explain the situation.
I have taken this approach before, and it was well-received: The flag was marked helpful, and the spamming user was indeed deleted:

[image: (Not flagging for this post.) The user "..." (meta.stackoverflow.com/users/...) has posted the same spam message at least twice in the past hour (meta Question IDs ... and ...). Since the user doesn't have any valuable to add (except for spam), can the account be nuked? – Apr 11 at 16:43 helpful]

Comment: Ahhh, flagging poor Mike. How dare you.

Comment: Just flagged it this way. Let's see how things go.

Comment: I think they try to avoid nuking cross site spammers right away to try and catch more spammers from same IP address, then they cast IP ban. Single site spam is more simple case and lead to account deletion within few hours from what I've seen so far.

Comment: The user is removed but the flag is still waiting for review. Yannis is right, I just did.