# Making customs flags on users with no activity

Tags: discussion, support, flags

Related to [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users) and [Reporting an inappropriate or offensive user name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213180/reporting-an-inappropriate-or-offensive-user-name).

The advice to manage a user that is offensive and has no activity to flag on is to use the *Contact Us* link and send an email.

1. Is it OK to raise a custom flag on one of our own posts like below, rather than send an email?:

   > [image]

Related but different:

[How do I flag a user with no posts left?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178221/how-do-i-flag-a-user-with-no-posts-left)

2. *If the user is added to [Smoke Detector's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266345/smokedetector) black list, how does this affect the profile without posts? - not applicable after feedback*

Comment: Blacklisted user for Smoke Detector only means that any future post of that user will be reported. That is all, it doesn't matter what posts the user got in the time of blacklisting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah thanks, that clears that up. So flagging is the best thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is totally okay to handle this by a flag on your own post. The thing is: the email has to be handled by a community manager, not a moderator. Flags end up where they are supposed to: a moderator.

(Questions related to Smoke Detector are better asked in the Tavern chat room, where Smoke Detector resides.)

Comment: so a custom flag is probably a better idea maybe?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is much less work than the *Contact Us*. I only use that one if I am really sure a SE employee has to solve the issue. If not, I just use a flag.

Comment: @MsYvette in addition to this answer, the reason why Patrick suggested to  ask Smokey-related in the Tavern is because Smokey has nothing to do with Stack Exchange as a company (it's user-created bot).

Comment: @AndrewT. ah k, I can edit smokey out of the question.