# Please delete user 2763826

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, offensive

As it is [not possible to flag users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61468/216199), I'm creating a post here to draw moderator attention to this user:

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763826/siegheil</strike>

The "highlights" are:

- Hateful name
- Inappropriate "About Me" text (in German language)
- A single trash answer

IMHO, *it* should be removed from SO.

Comment: Seems to have been done...

Comment: Hey, you moderators a doing great work!

Comment: You could also flag that one trash answer, choose Other and explain.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I used to choose "spam" for answers of this kind; thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please let this user come to Meta to complain about moderators being Nazis...please....

Comment: You can also submit two flags, one spam flag and one "Other" to notify about the offensive name.

Comment: @Bart That would almost be appropriate. Or... errr...?? hehe

Comment: Where's the [status-burninated] tag for trolls? (Flexo ♦ deserves the credit for the destruction here, by the way!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber it will be even better to have tag icon of Trogdor for that tag!