# Don't let me report my own profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

Just noticed the "report this profile" link in any profile page, which is nice.

However, can't see any reason why someone would need to report his/her own profile.

Can this link be removed when viewing own profile please?

Comment: Could be another way of contacting the team for account issues without having to flag one of your posts?

Comment: @Troyen You can just hit up "contact us" directly. No need to "report" a profile.

Comment: Thanks, now I have to create a sock to report my own profile :(

Comment: @rene or ask in the Tavern, I'm sure lots of people would love to comply! :D

Comment: Well, I've done some pretty dubious things, So much so I did consider reporting myself once. I'd say leave it there for now, you never know...

Comment: @rene I will save you the trouble, am going to report your profile.

Comment: I sense some rage quitters/new users with questions heavily downvoted/users with personal grudge against others who closed their questions, already planning to abuse this feature.

Comment: @DroidDev yeah, that's most likely the reason why they didn't do it until now, and if that will indeed happen too much, guess they'll throw this feature away. (or put a reputation threshold, like flagging)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: By the way, what led to this feature? Any specific event or meta request or just something that was planned for a while?

Comment: @cVplZ not sure, not a trace of official response there. But who knows... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard long standing request.  We don't want a reporting spree, and we're not sure the feature as is is adequate.  Thus the soft launch as we see how this version is used.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. Do anyone from the team is planning to post some official response somewhere, or can I add what you said to my [unofficial answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242784)?

Comment: And now [it's gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243284/report-this-profile-link-is-missing)?

Comment: Yes, it's gone @ShadowWizard. We didn't make a big deal out of announcing it because it was experimental. Only a very, very small percentage of reports were actually for what we intended (offensive avatars, display names, or "about me" sections), and the rest were either non-issues or should have been flags on posts instead.