# "Report this profile" link is missing

Tags: support, profile-page

The "report this profile" link is not visible under any profile page today, has this feature been removed temporarily or for good?

Comment: Let me guess: it was removed because it was "misused" for stuff that should have been handled by moderators instead.

Comment: Well, it was never announced officially so guess it was just a failed test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been removed, as confirmed in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61468/is-it-possible-to-flag-a-user-rather-than-just-individual-posts/242784#comment795133_242784) by [Jay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles) who is a senior Stack Exchange employee:

> The feature was intended for flagging a profile that was broadly offensive, but was mostly being used for situations where users should have been flagging a post, or where someone had an issue with a user (spam, suspected downvoting, Etc.) We may bring it back if we think we can target its use better, but it wasn't working as intended.

Comment: @cVplZ nah, pretty sure they got hundreds of "this user is [something here] handle/nuke/smite him" on totally legit users, with posts they could flag instead.

Comment: We also got a lot of people flagging profiles that had nothing obviously wrong with them, whose posts didn't seem to be problematic either. Nothing obviously wrong + nothing but the boilerplate email = lots of support time for what seemed to be non-problems.