# Sockpuppet admission

Tags: discussion, fun, sock-puppets

I figure it's time to let the cat out of the bag before someone else goes public with it, and it's just too hard living a lie.

Jon Skeet is my sockpuppet account.

Would a moderator please combine that account into my normal account for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll need a t-shirt sent to me now, too.

Comment: If would be kind of funny if a mod merged your account with Jon Skeet's.

Comment: this question is probably the best illustration of why reputation on meta is utterly meaningless ;-)

Comment: Hey, I claimed the "Jon Skeet" account months ago!

Comment: @mmyers- move your feet, lose your seat.

Comment: It is traditional to tag unfunny questions as "fun".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I used to be a sock puppet, but I have become independent now. I don't need the hand.

Comment: Don't you still feel ... *empty* inside?

Answer (score 23):

I'm Tony the Pony and so is my wife.

(On a more serious note, I'm still considering the idea of a sockpuppet account to see how much harder it really *is* to get votes for good answers without being a "known name".)

Comment: will you donate the gained rep to someone? *giving puppy eyed look*

Comment: @Jon: I've gotten good at spotting your style...you're gonna have to change it up...

Comment: I've considered this a few times since a lot of people complain that it's harder to get rep now than it was when the site started (and I've always contended that a good programmer need only spend 1-2 hours a day to hit the cap).  But then I risk getting addicted to SO again...

Comment: If you don't use that account to upvote yours, is it still a sockpuppet account? I think it would make a good experiment if you did what you said

Comment: You can borrow my account if you like.

Comment: I have thought of variation on this. Take Jon and someone else. Find some questions that both could be expected to answer. Get their answers and then randomly assign them to each user (and possibly a new user), post these answers and see which ones get the most up-votes. If the name does affect the votes we should see the ones posted under "Jon" being up-voted more than the other user (or the new user).

Comment: @Pollyanna:  Yep, there's nothing to refuel an addiction like adding alt characters in a game.  Personally, I'm not sure it's any harder to get rep, but I think it may be harder to get badges like "Great Question" or "Great Answer".

Comment: SO you shouldnt have a problem - 
SU a little harder. - 
META would be the most difficult.

Comment: Poor SF left out again...

Comment: @Jon, unrelated but do you work out? I've seen your devdays videos and you seem really fit.. I imagined differently :P

Comment: @Kop: Clearly the video doesn't do me justice. I'm not particularly overweight, but I'm horribly unfit.

Comment: @Jon, if you want to feel what it's like for the rest of us, you should start answering questions poorly as well. Just to get the full *authentic* experience.

Answer (score 22):

I admire your honesty in coming forward on such a difficult topic. Be strong!

Given your bravery, I feel compelled to admit that I've also had a [sockpuppet account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640/) for years. I cleverly changed the name so nobody would suss it out, but I think the jig is up.

Comment: So, according to the first answer, you are a sock puppet of Chacha102, and your sockpuppet is Geoffery....I'm getting confused...

Comment: There, now I've posted an answer as "Jeff," responded to myself as "Chacha," and adding some inane commentary as "Jonathan."

Comment: lol @Jonathan...wait...who the hell am I talking to...screw it, everyone gets an upvote

Comment: @Jeff - *LOL!* That's hilarious, I'm going to be grinning for the rest of the day... hehehe

Comment: You are acknowledging him?? You are breaking your own rules pal!

Comment: Proper credit should go to Jon B for outing you six months ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/suspended-user-creating-new-accounts/24738#24738

Comment: I am posting this from my latest sock puppet account. love, -Jeff Atwood ♦

Comment: Wow, that's like, way schizophrenic.

Answer (score 13):

I'll take a merge with Marc Gravell as long as I get his knowledge...screw the rep.

Comment: I'll take it only to get a t-shirt... screw the knowledge and the rep!

Comment: If I thought I could get a t-shirt out of the merge then I'm with you on that...

Answer (score 11):

I too would like to come clean.

I need [Jeff Atwood's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) Account merged with mine. Along with [Jonathan Sampson's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson).

I'd prefer to keep the account ID associated with Jeff's account.

(Hey.. I stay busy. High school tends to be really boring. Plus, I always wanted to have a name long enough that it broke the rep badge.)

Comment: @Pollyanna: You figured me out - It can get exhausting switching back and forth! (Oops, still logged in as Jonathan)

Comment: @Pollyanna Especially when I get into an argument with myself. (There we go)

Answer (score 7):

If you vote for me as moderator, I'll do it.

In fact, that'd be my campaign motto: "Vote for me and I'll merge your account"

<sub>may only be able to do it once; first come, first served; offer void in the US and countries where this would be illegal</sub>

Answer (score 5):

It started to become obvious.  The stress from leading a double life must have been too overwhelming of late.

Comment: Yeah.  And the tell-tale signs aren't pretty.  I don't remember much about the last few years, but friends have posted pictures of me doing rep off of dead rental laptops in dark alleys.  *shudder*  It's a long, slow climb, but I'm improving each day.

Comment: It must have been quite disturbing waking up one day with your hand shoved up a pony's arse.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I think the best way to break the addiction would be to get involved in some form of charity. For example to help you give up rep, we could split all Jon Skeet's points between every user on the site.

Answer (score 5):

I am Spartacus!

Comment: No, I am spartacus!

Answer (score 5):

But who is number 1?

Comment: "I am not a number"

Comment: "I am a __free man!__ "