# I've been downvoted for moving question to meta

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [So, what’s happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy)

Some people get very upset about their reputation loss. I just helped moving question of one of them off stackoverflow.com and now being downvoted a lot. Well, not much damage is going to be done as the guy doesn't have much rep left but anyway, but where's the script I heard are there to prevent such kind of behaviors?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a single person has downvoted you more than 5 times in a single day, the abnormalities script, when ran, will pick up on it and reverse those votes.

This script runs at least once a day, so give it 24 hours and you'll be fine.

Comment: Wow, he probably knew that, he stopped at 5 downvotes :)

Comment: @Chacha: Do you have inside knowledge of the magic number? I wasn't aware that it had been revealed.

Comment: @dmckee - Boundary testing is fun! ;-P

Comment: @dmckee Don't you know about my sock puppet accounts? :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42789/sockpuppet-admission/42790#42790

Comment: @dmckee: you can try it on stack exchange

Comment: Looks like boundaries wasn't tested that well, downvotes got deleted even though there was just 5 of them.

Comment: @vava, a moderator might have read this post and fixed it