# Delete an account I made by accident on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-accounts, merge-accounts

I accidentally made another account when trying to switch between Google accounts. Its name is [user333673](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333673/user333673).

And I also asked a question on it without realising it was not my "real" account.

So can a moderator please delete it or merge it with my "real" user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/191463/jonathan

I can post a question on Stack Overflow on the accident account to prove it is me. Or email a moderator or someone from the email specified.

Comment: For future reference: just flag one of the posts for moderator attention and explain the situation in the provided text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the text "Please delete me" to the About Me section of the unwanted account and I'll go in and merge them.  (I'm reasonably sure they're both your accounts.  This is just a precaution.)

Comment: I created an accidental account and gave a few answers with it. The name is Jon Skeet. If you could merge that with this account, that'd be awesome. kthx

Comment: @Earlz: And that is why I *always* follow the procedure.  :)

Comment: I added "Please Delete Me (merge with http://stackoverflow.com/users/191463/jonathan)"

Comment: @Earlz, dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42789/sockpuppet-admission