# Can I create a different username for myself and link that?

Tags: feature-request, support, user-accounts, display-names

Sometimes I ask a question from a theoretical perspective like: [Is NOW() a stable function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270765/is-now-a-stable-function)

Invariably I got loads of workaround answers.
For these types of questions I would love to have a username like: `theoretical_question`.
For other types of question I would like to have my normal username.

Can I create my own alter ego?

Comment: I think the rule of multiple accounts is "as long as they don't cross (i.e. vote up questions/answers) you're probably OK.

Comment: What do you think this would accomplish?

Comment: @Bill, people have alter ego's for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Nobody is going to treat your question differently based on your user name.  It sounds like you just want to use a tag.

Comment: @Bill: It sounds like he wants to expand his question by one sentences (like he did).

Comment: @Straitjacket: That is much better than a meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Disclaimer:*** This is a rhetorical answer, it's not supposed to answer you question but instead show a workaround.

No, you can't have aliases.

**Edit:** But as you did, you can use *words*. Okay, that was mean, I know, I take it back and apologize. Joke aside, just add to your question that it is theoretical...that's enough, just like that.

Also, [you can have sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42789/sockpuppet-admission) (multiple accounts)...as many as you want, [it's not all evil even if it is a sock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose).

**Edit2:** But was Won't said, there's a pretty good chance that those sockpuppets will be permanently glued to your hand if they're encountered.

Comment: However, socks are subject to merging at any time if/when they are discovered.  There is no guarantee that they are allowed.  In addition, you might get your butt suspended as well if there is cross-vote-mojination.