# reference to rules prohibiting to write from more than one account

Tags: support, moderation, abuse, account-suspension

My clone account guenavan is suspended together with my account vgv8 - why?

Please give me any reference to the rules prohibiting to write from multiple accounts.

Why was my second account  guenavan account suspended?
What rules have I infringed from it.

Plz give me refernece to rules

Comment: I think the rule is: One account per personality.

Comment: Seriously? You think it should be OK to cheat a suspension by having multiple accounts?

Comment: And here is a reference to another case of a suspended user creating multiple accounts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/suspended-user-creating-new-accounts

Comment: @Kop I was making a 'multiple personality reference'. Whooosh.

Comment: @user: If you can't accept the reasons for your ban and make an effort to improve your behavior and attitude, it might be time for you to find another site to ask questions and post answers.  I've heard great things about experts exchange.

Comment: Car wreck in progress, film at 11.  Seriously, there are some things I would do differently if I were in charge but the very fact that you're still able to whine about a reasonably applied suspension on this site speaks volumes to how patient the admins are with wonky users.

Comment: @Jon B. How do you know how many people work from one account? or from the same ip-address from different accounts? The answer to the latter question is half of Siberia, the territory equal to US. The answer to former question is unknown for you. Do not jump to any conclusions. We are here the whole asylum hacking psychic clinic computers tonight

Comment: @Whooosh, exactly. Why does Jon B insist in denying this site to our God (Father, Son and Holy Spirit)?

Answer (score 7):

The suspension is probably intended to stop **you** from doing whatever you were doing.

It's not like an account on it's own would do anything bad, usually it's the owner of the account. So it's only logical to suspend all accounts of a person if it is determined that that person needs a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

There are no written rules on stack overflow, just common sense.

<s>Probably you upvoted yourself from one account to another.</s>

Having more than one account per-se is completely legit, as long as there is no cross upvoting. Email team@stackoverflow.com for more information.

**EDIT**: you have been banned with one account and created another to evade the ban. Obviously, that goes against the "common sense" I talked about above, hence the reason for your suspension.

Comment: Please don't appeal to "common sense" in this case.

Comment: I did not create another after banning. I already had it long time ago. And even before registering here... Do you imply that you have only one Email or one identity in internet? Does your religion prohibit multiple identities? This site doesm't, I see multiple buttons while signing-in into this site. Even one identity in this site permits different usernames, if you did not realize it yet