# Is there a way to sift through a list of unregistered users?

Tags: feature-request, support, search, unregistered-users

Extension of comment discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49759/possible-duplicate-user/49762#49762). Is there a way to look at all unregistered users? The "Users" tab seems to only indicate registered users. It doesn't necessarily have to be allowed to people besides moderators, but I'm wondering if there is any simple method for this.

When I first registered at Stack Overflow, I came across a pair of questions about a week or a half of one apart (since it's a `[sharepoint]` question, they were still on the same page). Not many people looked at them, but I noticed they were duplicates in the actual code body, and subsequently saw that the users were almost the same: their names were different by one letter. Unfortunately, I couldn't comment on them at the time, so I left it for others to come notice. Shortly after I started to gain momentum, I found myself actually answering a question by a third account of the same name. It wasn't a duplicate question, nor was the question a fourth account asked (which has two questions to its name). The most likely scenario is that this user simply doesn't wish to register, and the cooke is expiring.

In light of the discussion cited at the start, I figured I should report it... so I did a search on Users and found nothing. Sifting through my Answers let me find [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318848/) [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308005/) out of at least 4, but there are a few others. So I was wondering, is there a method to search through the usernames of unregistered users in order to find the additional accounts? If there isn't one, then this would be a handy feature-request.

Comment: I think registered user [list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43948/a-whole-lot-of-users-in-need-of-merging) need to finish first before going into unregistered list

Comment: Oh, definitely, priority should definitely go to registered user account merging. But I shan't imagine that it is wise to simply ignore unregistered users until then. If someone spots such a situation, it would be nice to know that there is maybe some possible ability to check for whether it is limitted to just the accounts which you've actually seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SOFU dev team and diamond moderators have a search tool that will search all users, registered and unregistered.  To my knowledge it is not exposed anywhere to regular users, including those with access to the 10k moderation tools.

When you find things like this, the best thing to do is flag one of the user's posts for moderator attention, or email the site contact address: team@stackoverflow.com, team@serverfault.com or team@superuser.com.

Comment: That's sufficient. Only the people who need to access this stuff really need to have access to it, so that works perfectly. Thanks!