# Why was the "convert to edit" action disabled?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

Today I handled a "not an answer" flag for a post that should have been part of the original question.

I attempted to use the "convert to edit" moderator tool but it was disabled (radio button greyed out).

The post had been edited twice by other users, for formatting.  Is this a reason to deny the "convert to edit" function?  If it is not the reason, what is?

[image: screen shot]

Here is a link to the post on Mathematica.SE: [(31301)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31301/121)

Comment: Link to the post?

Comment: @Anna Oh, so this is not normal behavior?  It's on [Mathematica.SE], but I'll add a link in a moment.

Comment: Is the now-deleted answer by the same user, or by another unregistered user with the same display name? “Convert to edit” is only enabled if it's the same user.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It might be, but I'm not immediately aware of the mechanics there. Having a link for context is always handy because it allows us (or at least me :)) to see if there's anything immediately obvious about it that I didn't think of right away.

Comment: @Anna Okay, sorry for not including that as standard procedure.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No worries. (And sorry if I sounded dismissive; that's unintentional.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I merged the profiles, but since both of them are unregistered, that probably won't do much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was posted by the same person using a different (unregistered) account.

As Gilles notes in the comments, the "convert to edit" option is only available when the answer and the question are both posted by the same user.

Comment: I see.  The use of the same email address and therefore Gravatar threw me off.  To me this is more evidence that [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192191/158428) and ones like it are not without merit, as this kind of housekeeping affects the mechanics of the site.

Comment: I'm personally starting to consider doing away with unregistered profiles altogether. They're typically more trouble than they're worth. The distinction is obscure and the support/maintenance costs are fairly high for us and the moderators.

Comment: @Anna that's a pretty major change, what will you do with existing unregistered profiles? I recall seeing some active for years and contributing hundreds of helpful posts...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The key part of my comment is "starting to consider". :) That is one of the issues we'd need to resolve. My expectation would be that most unregistered profiles get lost and go dormant since keeping a live cookie for years can be a challenge. I haven't yet looked at any actual data to support or dispute that assumption.

Comment: Cheers and good luck with that... would love to hear updates when there will be such. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: I was just posting [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197263/135505) on similar issues. A comment there pointed back to your comment here.