# Add timestamp to find user tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

Currently moderators have a tool that enables them to find users by searching across various fields for a search term.

While the result ordering is by User ID (which gives a rough idea of the age thus the creation date of the account) it would be useful to include an additional column in the results that is the explicit creation date, or  perhaps more usefully the last active date (which may or may not be a better default ordering anyway).

Comment: Can't you use the API for that? A bit similar as I've done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291792/158100)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done. The results now show `Created` and `Last activity`. Results are also sortable, and default to `LastActivityDate desc` for sort.

> It took five whole years…
> But better later than never…
> Columns showing now!

Comment: I am curious about the process in place here. First of all don't get me wrong, I'm thrilled that it was done and it's awesome, however this feature request was not even under review; It doesn't have a very high score. What made it to be chosen for implementation, over the thousands of other requests, and hundreds of those with a [tag:status-review] tag?

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar: I believe work on revamping this mod tool was already underway for other reasons. It just happened to line up with this feature request as well.

Comment: @V2Blast fair, but usually we get status updates: review, planned, etc. :)

Comment: I only became aware of this post once the work was done. The work itself was initiated based on a post from the Moderators private team.